# Sharepoint List - Number as percentage with default value setting

Tags: sharepoint-online, list-form, powerapp, number

I'm working on a PowerApp linked to a list as data source and I get weird display on every number displayed as a percentage (x100).

I'm trying to set a number column/field with a value between 0 and 100 and a default value to 100. However I failed getting it working on both Sharepoint List and PowerApp edit form.

With this settings (cf picture), if i try to add an entry my default value is 10 000%.
So I tried with Max Value 1 and Default Value 1 : It worked fine in Sharepoint however in PowerApp the display went from 0 to 1 not from 0 to 100.

In the near future, I will have hundred of those so I hope I am missing something... not that the product is missing something...

Do you have any solution/advise on this that doesn't involve handling myself the datacard template for percentage?

[image: Sharepoint Field Edit Form]